# Essential safety features of an EMG/medical grade device?

Tags: operational-amplifier

EMG consists of an electrode gel skin interface, op-amps with a certain gain and an ADC. Question is in the context of passive electrodes.

What are the essential safety features of such types of hardware?

One option to make such hardware safer is to make it battery powered. What other safety features are generally recommended?

Comment: This may be a better question if you ask about *implementation techniques* that help with implementing the requirements placed upon such systems. "Safety features" is a nice term but it implies something that isn't true: it's not the "safety features" that are important, but the requirements that gave rise to them, and then the quite varied techniques available to fulfill them. The choice of techniques depends on one's creativity (engineering is an art too!), cost and market constraints, prior experience, and so on.

Comment: thanks @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I think I will study the requirements and then ask about implementation techniques for specific safety requirements that I need help with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safety features are not quite "recommended": they are a legal requirement for putting the device on the market.

The law refers to standards that define the specific requirements, and the most basic requirements are given in IEC 60601. An EMG measuring system would be a class IIa medical device, with type BF applied parts - that should help navigate the standardese to start with, I hope.

The 60601 standard prescribes requirements on insulation systems, leakage currents, and testing of those.

> One option to make such hardware safer is to make it battery powered.

"Safety", or, rather, suitably low risk for given application, is determined by adherence to particular requirements.

Battery power is just one *means* of satisfying *some* of the requirements. It's quite simple to make a battery powered external electrode electrophysiology system that, for example, exceeds the DC leakage currents on the electrodes in some single-fault scenarios (and it shouldn't). So - battery power by itself is only means to an end, but not the  end itself. The design has to be guided by the requirements.

The best I can suggest is to, ahem, procure 60601 standards relevant to your application, and investigate the applicable requirements they set out.

> EMG consists of an electrode gel skin interface, op-amps with a certain gain and an ADC.

Yes - and no. EMG active electrodes can be gel-free. There are EMG front-ends both modern and old that don't use op-amps but rather connect to the ADC through an impedance-lowering buffer with no gain. There are electrophysiology front-ends that are direct-to-digital, with a charge-balancing ADC connected straight to the electrodes. Almost any front-end architecture has its own quirks. Going with the "simplest" approach is not always truly simplest - often, the "simplicity" is just a false impression stemming from familiarity. We instinctively treat what we're familiar with as "simpler" than the new and unfamiliar. Technical innovation happens when this human tendency is understood and kept in check :) The requirements come handy in disentangling what's essential from what's just an implementation choice.

> What are the essential safety features of such types of hardware?

The language is rather important here, because it conveys true meaning: first there are safety requirements, determined according to a risk analysis. Then there are safety features that *implement* those requirements. It's best to familiarize itself with requirements first, to better understand why certain implementation choices are made.

And finally: a medical device isn't just because it connects to the body with electrodes. If you use EMG in a consumer game controller, it's not a medical device, although good engineering practice would dictate that you transplant most requirements from the 60601 world.

Comment: Thanks. We have already planned to go through the 60601 standards.

Comment: NFP 99 standards are what my hospital tests to, and they will be a good deal cheaper and easer to acquire than 60601.